# How to style an svg using external stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG file and I want to include it in an HTML page. I want to style it using an external CSS file, but I don't want to include the stylesheet reference in the SVG itself.

Is this possible? Then how would you accomplish this?

Comment: Yes this is possible and I'm pretty sure, it's already answered on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434094/how-to-style-svg-with-external-css)

Comment: @Clijsters The answers you link to appear to suggest this is _not_ really possible: "the CSS needs to be defined inside of the SVG file" ... "the paths within your symbol can't be styled independently via external CSS -- you can only set the properties for the entire symbol with this method." (?)

Comment: _"Your main.css file would only have an effect on the content of the SVG if the SVG file is included inline in the HTML:"_ I suggested a question. not an answer, didn't I? I'll answer this one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434094/how-to-style-svg-with-external-css), it is possible to style an SVG only if it's part of your DOM. If you load it using e.g. an `<img>` tag, as a background or so, only CSS code which is direct in your SVG-File would have effect.

Like described in the question's [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20720935/4068240) this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) illustrates how you can use inline SVG.

However, if you want your SVG to stay in an external ressource, and not have to *copy&paste* it in your template, every time it changes (I hope you didn't think about this kind of 'solution'), you could load it dynamically into your DOM with a simple (untested) AJAX call:

```
//Assuming you have jQuery available
$.ajax({
    url: './mysvgFile.svg',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.childNodes.length > 0) { //should be one, _could_ be more
            $('.myDiv').append(data.childNodes[0]);
        } else {
            console.log('invalid SVG');
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.error('Error loading SVG!');
    }
});
```

At this point your stylesheets can manipulate elements in your SVG.